# How do I remove a checkbutton when it is checked

Tags: python, tkinter

I have built a simple to-do list and I am trying to get the checkbox to remove itself when it is checked(to signify that the task has been completed)

I am not sure how I need to be implementing the function in order to remove itself.  Can anyone help me out with this.  I've combed through a list of pages and none of them have really indicated how you do this.

```
class App(object):

def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.grid()
    self.addFrame = Frame(master)
    self.addFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='N')
    self.listFrame = Frame(master)
    self.listFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NW')
    self.todoList = []
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.entryBox = Entry(self.frame, width = 15)
    self.entryBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='N')

    self.addButton = Button(self.frame, text="<-ADD->", command=self.add)
    self.addButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='N')


def removeCheckButton(self):
    # - CONFUSED HOW TO REMOVE THE SPECIFIC CHECKBUTTON
    pass

def add(self):
    entry = self.entryBox.get()
    self.entryBox.delete(0, END)
    self.todoList.append(entry)
    print self.todoList
    var1 = IntVar()
    self.buttonList = []
    for n in range(len(self.todoList)):
        lx = Checkbutton(self.listFrame, text=self.todoList[n], variable=self.todoList[n], command=removeCheckButton)
        lx.grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='NW')
        self.buttonList.append(lx)
        print self.buttonList
```

Comment: As a first comment: `command=removeCheckButton` should be `command=self.removeCheckButton`.

Comment: On most widgets AFAIK you can use destroy() or grid_forget().  To do this you would have to use partial to pass the number to the function and then destroy/forget self.buttonList[number].  Try it and see how you do. Import partial from functools and call the function with command=partial(self.removeCheckButton, number).  Info on grid_forget at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: I think Im still having trouble understanding how to implement the destroy.  Im not sure how to pass the number from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this. your `add` is a bit strangely designed (and incorrectly IMO), so I modified it slightly as well as other parts.

```
from tkinter import *


class App(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.addFrame = Frame(master)
        self.addFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='N')
        self.listFrame = Frame(master)
        self.listFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NW')
        self.todoList = []
        self.buttonList = []  #<--- button list is here now
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.entryBox = Entry(self.frame, width = 15)
        self.entryBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='N')

        self.addButton = Button(self.frame, text="<-ADD->", command=self.add)
        self.addButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='N')


    def removeCheckButton(self, button_no):
        # - CONFUSED HOW TO REMOVE THE SPECIFIC CHECKBUTTON
       # print(button_no, self.buttonList[button_no])
        #self.buttonList[button_no].grid_forget()
        self.buttonList[button_no].destroy()
       # del self.buttonList[button_no]
       # del self.todoList[button_no]


    def add(self):
        entry = self.entryBox.get()
        self.entryBox.delete(0, END)
        self.todoList.append(entry)
        print(self.todoList)
        var1 = IntVar()
        #self.buttonList = [] #<--- not sense having this here
      #  for n in range(len(self.todoList)): #<-- this for also very strange here.
        n = len(self.buttonList)
        lx = Checkbutton(self.listFrame,
                         text=self.todoList[n],
                         variable=self.todoList[n],
                         command=lambda ni=n: self.removeCheckButton(ni))
        lx.grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='NW')
        self.buttonList.append(lx)
         #   print(self.buttonList)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

P.S.
I use python 3, but except the `import part`, the code should execute for you. Probably it needs more fixing, but the checkboxes get destroyed now as they supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
What else would you offer as far as fixing?  I gave myself this project to better learn the program.  Any suggestion is obviously well accepted.

Comment: No worries. I did not go into all details of the program. I just focussed on the checkboxes destruction. Check it if it works, modify it to your liking, and if you have new questions/problems just make new question. One quick thing, when you destroy a checkboox, probably would need to also remove associated elements from `self.todoList` and `self.buttonList`.

Comment: I do get a list out of range error on the checkbutton line

Comment: Have you modified something from what I uploaded. It works for me. If not, than maybe there are some differences between python 3 and 2 in this code.

Comment: Its working now, something wrong in how I transcribed it over.  Thanks again